# Zebra Label Printing using windows Application giving Error

Tags: c#, winforms, zebra-printers

I have downloaded windows sample application from zebra technologies to print labels using its sdk.

When i try to run it detects the print installed but gives me following error

[image]

Please guide me what should i do to resolve error

Comment: Is your intention to design labels or are you only handling labels that has already been constructed elsewhere (e.g. UPS web service)?

Comment: yes my intention is to print different types of label sheets using my application

Comment: The manual says that error 60 means ZBR_ERROR_PRINTER_NOT_SUPPORTED.  If you can't find a slot anywhere on the printer where you could insert your credit card then you surely found the underlying problem.  If not then pick up the phone and call Zebra support.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to print labels that were delivered from a UPS web service (in ZPL format), and I solved it using this library: [SharpZebra](https://sharpzebra.codeplex.com/)

I then could handle the label layout as a string and print it with the following code:

```
// Initialize printer with its Windows printer name
var printer = new ZebraPrinter("ZDesigner GX420d");
printer.Print(labelData);
```

It has worked perfectly for more than a year in production by now.

Comment: is that possible to do using web application (asp.net), as in asp.net website code will be of sever side it doesn't work. so i thought to make windows service for this and print using windows service periodically

Comment: In our solution the printing is performed by a Windows service, so it should work just fine. I'm not sure about how it would work from ASP.Net server side, in practice the IIS user would be responsible for the printing then, I guess.